# ContentModerationStateFormatter does not work

Tags: views, entities

I am building Views with a field to display the entity's content_moderation_state.
For FieldFormatter, I select 'Content moderation state', which is the ContentModerationStateFormatter defined within Content Moderation module.
On executing the view, I see that the field content is not so formatted.  The machine name, not the label is displayed.
In fact, when debugging, I find that we do not even hit the ContentModerationStateFormatter!  Views is displaying the machine name and disregarding the request to format.

Has anyone else had this problem or have a solution?
Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please note, that the content moderation module is still in Beta as for the current stable Drupal core. You should always check the [Drupal issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/drupal?text=&status=Open&priorities=All&categories=All&version=All&component=content_moderation.module) for issues with it.

If you are on Drupal 8.4.4, there is still an issue with the moderation state formatter, which has been fixed for 8.5: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2859381
Applying these fixes to Drupal 8.4.4 made it work for us.

If you are on a Drupal version before 8.4, you may even have to [migrate the workflows to 8.4](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2896630) first, as there have been some breaking changes to the workflows module while maturing to stable.

Comment: Thank you, Mario; yes I am on 8.4.4. My content_moderation states show in a view by using a relationship to Content Moderation state.  For a short term solution, I will sanitize the string to get "In progress" instead of "in_progress".  Look forward to 8.5, tho!